# Have to press enter twice at a point for python to run

Tags: python

I'm sure this issue was asked a lot of times, but I am not capable to fix it in my own code:

The code is supposed to take an input of integers and display the biggest/smallest element.
I am suspecting the issue is in the last 6 lines but it looks to me that everything is allright and no change needed. I'd appreciate any help

```
tablou = input("Introduceti valori separate cu spatiu: ")
b = tablou.split()
extrema = input("Gasesc valoarea (min)ima sau (max)ima?: ")

t = [] # initial  list with int() contents
for l in b:
    r = int(l)
    t.append(r)

# .sort sorteaza de la mic mai mare. Make personal note on .sort(reverse = True)
def main0():
    t.sort()
    return t[0]

def main1():
    t.sort(reverse= True)
    return t[0]

valoare = input()
if extrema.lower() == "min":
    valoare = main0()
elif extrema.lower() =="max":
    valoare = main1()
print(valoare)
```

Here's a particular output:

```
Introduceti valori separate cu spatiu: >? 1 2 3
Gasesc valoarea (min)ima sau (max)ima?: >? max
>?
3
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try creating a minimal example, and you will find it is `valoare = input()`.

It looks like you accidentally copy-pasted it from the `extrema =` line?  It is not needed for values in general.  You can do `valoare = None` if you want, or omit it entirely.

Comment: Thank you! This fixed it, for some reason the IDE autocompleted "input" instead on intended "int", I'll start using "None" for further cases as you sugested.

Answer (score 0):

You have three `input` statements in your control flow, so you must hit `ENTER` three times:

```
tablou = input("Introduceti valori separate cu spatiu: ")

extrema = input("Gasesc valoarea (min)ima sau (max)ima?: ")

valoare = input()
```

This last one does nothing for you; you immedately over-write its value.
Remove it, and your problem should be solved.

Cu plăcere